# How to install python 3.7.0 using pyenv?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-14.04, python-3.7, pyenv

I tried to install with the command
        "pyenv install 3.7.0" 
and getting the error as follows

```
Downloading Python-3.7.0.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.0/Python-3.7.0.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.7.0...
ERROR: The Python ssl extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?

Please consult to the Wiki page to fix the problem.
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems

BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 14.04 using python-build 20180424)
```

I have checked with the solutions from https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems and tried

```
CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/openssl \
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib64 \
pyenv install -v 3.7.0
```

Again I am facing the same error as

```
The Python ssl extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?
```

Also tried to install python versions less than 3.7 which all are installed without error. Is there any dependent package or version update that I am missing here. 
I have openssl version

```
OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any dependent package or version update that I am missing here.

Yes, unfortunately there is. Python 3.7.0 requires OpenSSL 1.0.2. I couldn't find a better source than the dev mailing list. So far I've been unsuccessful getting Python 3.7.0 working on Ubuntu 14.04, as getting the right version of OpenSSL installed and not conflicting has been a trick.

> Python 3.7: Require OpenSSL >=1.0.2

https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2018-January/151718.html

Answer (score 12):

You can install the same by first installing openssl@1.1 by the command

```
    brew install 'openssl@1.1'
```

And the you can install python3.7 using:

```
    CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)" pyenv install 3.7.0
```

Or if you don't want to install any specific version for openssl, then you can use the below command for openssl package.

```
    CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl=$(brew --prefix openssl)" pyenv install 3.7.0
```

Comment: Can't you just `brew install python` or `brew upgrade python`?  I did and it appears to install dependencies gdbm, openssl, sqlite. It is currently python 3.7.2 though so maybe this was an issue previously